# ASP.NET Core 2 EmailSender exception with Sendgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, sendgrid

I'm trying to implement SendGrid in [Angular project template with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=visual-studio).

I'm using this example: [Account confirmation and password recovery in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x)

Unfortunately I always get this error (status: 500):

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'MyWebApp.Extensions.EmailSender' while attempting to activate 'MyWebApp.Controllers.AuthenticationController'

Here is the Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody]RegistrationViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var userIdentity = _mapper.Map<AppUser>(model);
    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(userIdentity, model.Password);

    if (!result.Succeeded)
        return new BadRequestObjectResult(Errors.AddErrorsToModelState(result, ModelState));

    //Enable account confirmation
    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(userIdentity);
    var callbackUrl = Url.EmailConfirmationLink(userIdentity.Id, code, Request.Scheme);
    await _emailSender.SendEmailConfirmationAsync(model.Email, callbackUrl);

    //await _appDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    return new OkObjectResult("Account created");
}
```

And the EmailSender:

```
public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
{
    public EmailSender(IOptions<AuthMessageSenderOptions> optionsAccessor)
    {
        Options = optionsAccessor.Value;
    }

    public AuthMessageSenderOptions Options { get; } //set only via Secret Manager

    public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
    {
        return Execute(Options.SendGridKey, subject, message, email);
    }

    public Task Execute(string apiKey, string subject, string message, string email)
    {
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
        var msg = new SendGridMessage()
        {
            From = new EmailAddress(<email-address>, <name>),
            Subject = subject,
            PlainTextContent = message,
            HtmlContent = message
        };
        msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(email));
        return client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
    }
}
```

I tried to write the `apiKey` directly in the code, but same result.
I've already successfully added a user in the database, but without SendGrid.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the service and its abstraction is registered with the service collection so that the service provider is aware of how to resolve them

*Startup.ConfigureServices*

```
services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);
```

Comment: They were already registered. I've forgot to show it in the question. Is the sequence important? They are added after `services.AddMvc()`

Comment: @GSeriousB if you review the documentation you linked to in your question you will see where they registered them after.

Comment: I moved the code at the end, but same error. Probably the problem is somewhere else. I'll find it out. Thanks for Help!